# AVCaptureSession's stopRunning - when to call

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm making an app that takes pictures. It consists of two view controllers connected via a `tabBarController`. On one of the viewControllers is the camera screen. It has a `UIView` which has the sole purpose of displaying the contents of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

I've hooked up the inputs and outputs, and have a live feed of the camera's view displayed on my `UIView`. Since I have 2 view controllers connected by a `tabBarController`, I make sure I call `stopRunning` whenever I'm not on my camera's viewController - when the user tabs to the other viewController.

Currently, I've implemented it as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    session.startRunning()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    session.stopRunning()
}
```

Whenever I'm on the camera screen with the session running, my iPhone 5 heats up - something I expected - probably due to the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` object's demand for resources. My above attempt is to stop the `session` wherever it's not needed. However, I feel like I haven't covered all the grounds.

If my app goes to background, will the `session` continue? I used some `println` statements to track my viewController life - cycle methods, and found that `viewWillDisappear` is not called when app is retired to the background.

Does that mean my `session` continues to run and my camera is still trying to provide the feed? I'm suspect this may be an issue, because the phone still feels warm after a long while.